# How to avoid point stacks?

Tags: qgis

When geocoding a dataset of about 500 addresses I get a vector point layer. So far everything is fine. The problem is, that the dataset contains multiple entries with the same address. The result is a point stack, in which one point covers one or more points that lie beneath the point on the top. Of course this is a correct behaviour, because: same address = same coordinates. But: When viewing the map, information is lost.

So my question: Is there a possibility to automatically arrange these points not on top of each other but side by side?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Points Displacement tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/pointsdisplacement.html).

It should disperse your overlapping points - although there may be limitations to how many points you can move.

Alternatively is there any reason not to delete the duplicate data or join it into a single point for each address? Or you could display a count of the number of points at the same address depending on what you want to show.

Comment: I had a look at that tool but some problems with the syntax (I'm quite new to the console). But I found the Points Displacement Renderer, which should do exactly what I want.... BUT: When activating this tool, it displaces all points within the current view, not only those that overlap. Is there no setting to define something like a displacement radius? Unfortunately it is no option to delete duplicate points, because every point represents a certain company at this adress and the colour of the point shows the line of business.

Comment: If you're having problems have you searched and run the tool from the Processing Toolbox? (Q geoalgorithms > Vector Geometry tools). This will bring up a window / interface for the tool where you can enter the variables and run it without needing worrying about syntax.